# Layout acting weird with login example

Tags: android, android-layout

Just created new project with android login example layout, when in portrait everything looks okay then i change orientation and text in email box does not look like hint, from code there is .getText and then .setText to save values, but it seems is setting hint text to normal text after changing orientation

Here is example:[image: Portrait]
Changing orientation: [image: Changed]

Comment: show your code buddy

Comment: Default code from Android Predefined examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***when change orientation activity restart that's why your text gone and hint showing again.***

to stop this add below code in your android manifest file where you have declare your activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

read more detail about [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)